# Populate dependent combox with Unique values VBA excel

Tags: combobox

I have created a user form for adding inventory.
I have 2 combobox in the form

1. Category = combobox1 (housekeeping, Electricals, Cafetria etc) for these categories I am populating combox1 with rowsource property
2. Itemsname - combobox2 - I want to populate this combobox based on the category selected in combobox 1
   The problem I am facing is the items name repeat if there are more than 1 itemsname then all items name show up in the combobox2 which i dont want. I want to see unique values. I will give you example of entries

ColumnA(Category)     ColumnB(itemsname)   ColumnC (Vendorname)
Cafeteria              Beans                Cafe Coffee Day
Housekeeping           liquid soap          Sevak Industries
IT                      Monitors            Infotech solutions
IT                     Keyboard             Infotech solutions
IT                     Monitors             Raj computers

see screenshot the above columns gets messed up : https://prnt.sc/10cbh30

Now in the above example I populate categories combobox 1 with unique values because number of categories are fixed so I have saved them separately and I pick them with rowsource

The main problem arises when I populate combobox 2 with items name. Same Item can be bought from different vendors so Monitors we are buying from different vendors so there are two entries. In combox 2 I see 2 entries of monitors but I want to see only one since the name is same.
Note I am using for loop and adding items in the loop in combobox 2 so it scans each entries of monitor twice so it adds up monitor twice
Can anyone help on this I am frustrated I cant figure out how to get unique values

Comment: Waiting for help on above request

Comment: Still waiting for help